# Open an asp classic frame in a view mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, asp-classic

I need some help about if it's possible to get an asp frame and open it inside a MVC View. I researched this but I didn't find nothing about a solution for this case. So, if  some one had this problem to solve and could help me with something I will appreciate. I really don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

One (and possibly the only?) solution for this would be to use an iframe on the MVC view with a source URL of the classic ASP page. I can't see any other way of doing it as they are two unrelated technologies, so any solution would revolve around making the classic ASP page 'appear' to be part of the MVC page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use System.net.Webrequest to call the classic asp page and then pass that content to the MVC view.

Comment: Good point. But this method would have the caveat that the page would have to be pretty much static HTML - buttons, postbacks and javascript would all be very unlikely to work.

Comment: depending on how you work with it, keep in mind all webpages are static content, your still linking the same js files so java scrip it's an issue, the and the content being called is classic asp not webforms so viewstate isn't an issue.

Comment: No but the postback URL of any button would likely be wrong as it will post back to the the .NET page not the classic ASP page.